# Is the order of std::env::args guaranteed to remain consistent over multiple calls?

Tags: rust

Is the iterator returned by the `std::env::args` family of functions guaranteed to remain consistent throughout the execution of the program (i.e. only set at most once during process startup)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the documentation doesn't say so, so no, it's not guaranteed.

Now, that having been said...

> Returns the arguments which this program was started with (normally passed via the command line).
>
> -[`std::env::args` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.args.html)

That would strongly imply that the result won't change.  It's not *impossible* that the result could change, but it's clearly not the intent for that to happen.